# rescue from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Wondering whether it's possible to rescue from a scope in Active Record

My model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> {where("is_active = 't'")}
  validates_inclusion_of :is_active, :in => [true, false]
end
```

In the controller, I have a function which may returns a single active question (if any)

```
def get_active_question
  begin
    @question = Question.active.first
  end
end
```

I tried with `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :no_record_error`, but this seems to have no effect

How can I catch/rescue the exception when no active question is returned? (I'd like to render another view). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope will never raise an exception. You use where not `find` (which can raise en exception)

```
def get_active_question
  @question = Question.active.first

  if @question
    # you have a question 
    render 'one_view'
  else 
    # no active questions
    render 'another_view'
  end
end
```